# Subset tibble (tidyverse) with indexes (short notation)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I want to subset a numeric value from a tibble tibble based on only indexes. For example if I want the 2nd row and the 3th column I want to use `tibble[2,3]`.

However this returns a `tibble` instead of a single number.

I know it is possible to use `tibble[2,] %>% pull(3)` but isn't there a shorter option comparable with the data.frame way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways. Either will work just as well for data frames or for tibbles.

```
library(tibble)
x = as_tibble(mtcars)
## The problem
x[1, 1]
##  A tibble: 1 x 1
#     mpg
#   <dbl>
# 1    21

## Solution 1: [.data.frame has drop = TRUE by default. Tibble switches
## the default to drop = FALSE, but you can still use the argument:
x[1, 1, drop = TRUE]
# [1] 21

## Solution 2: Use [[ to get a single column as a vector, and [ to
## pull the element you want
x[[1]][1]
[1] 21
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the option of the double square brackets

Comment: `pull` is just a "pipeable" version of `[[`. The description of `?pull` begins *"This works like `[[` for local data frames..."*.